# UITabBarItem over the separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a question concerning the circular green UITabBarItem (vide screenshot). I need to place it over the separator - the question is, how to do it?

The screenshot is under the following link:
http://send-picture.com/img-55d8d70357dd2.html

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: which view is it added to right now? or is it added via storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `UITabBar` property `clipToBounds` value to `NO`

After that you can add button subview to your `UITabBar` and place it in the center of tab bar.

Also in this case you need handle your custom button touch separatelly